# How can I play an audio random when a button is clicked in WP8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have tried this code, but it doesn't work.

```
 public void Play()
    {
        int randomIndex = -1;
        var sound1 = "/Assets/Audio/baby-crying-08.mp3";
        var sound2 = "/Assets/Audio/sound1.wav";
        string [] rawRef = {sound1,sound2};
        MediaElement mp = new MediaElement();
        try
        {
            randomIndex = random.Next(rawRef.Length);
           mp.Source = new Uri(rawRef[randomIndex], UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
           mp.Play();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
```

how to play an audio file randomly ?

Comment: what is the problem your are facing

take a look at this https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-1-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-20-Playing-Video-and-Audio-in-a-MediaElement-Control

Comment: Actually I want to play song at random function but I have put media source in code behind it doesn't play So how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

`MainPage.xaml`:

```
 <MediaElement x:Name="audio0" Source="/Audio/xh.mp3" AutoPlay="False" />
 <MediaElement x:Name="audio1" Source="/Audio/y.mp3" AutoPlay="False" />
```

`MainPage.xaml.cs`:

```
private Random _random = new Random();
private  int randomIndex = -1;
public void Playsound()
{  
    MediaElement [] rawRef = { audio0, audio1 };
    try
    {
        randomIndex = _random.Next(rawRef.Length);                
        if(randomIndex==0)
        {
            audio0.Play();
        }
        else if (randomIndex == 1)
        {
            audio1.Play();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        MessageBox.Show("Message:"+e.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem. You need use `Play()` method after media opened. Moreover you need add `MediaElement` control to your xaml. Remember to check your files paths. Look for this code:

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
private Random _random = new Random();

public void Play()
{
    int randomIndex = -1;
    var sound1 = "/Assets/cos.wav";
    var sound2 = "/Assets/xx.mp3";
    string[] rawRef = { sound1, sound2 };
    try
    {
        randomIndex = _random.Next(rawRef.Length);
        MediaElement.Source = new Uri(rawRef[randomIndex], UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}

private void OnMediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MediaElement.Play();
}

private void OnMediaFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Exception: {0}, Sound: {1}", e.ErrorException.Message, MediaElement.Source.ToString());
}
```

MainPage.xaml:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="MediaElement" AutoPlay="False" 
              MediaOpened="OnMediaOpened" 
              MediaFailed="OnMediaFailed" />
```

Comment: I have tried these code , but it shows  a error '3123 An error has occurred'

Comment: Check Capabilities in WMAppManifest.xml, and check  ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PLAYBACK.

Comment: If you have checked this capability, i have no idea what is wrong. Could you upload your solution??